Aws-cli configuration issue for s3
Just today I started to get this error message about 'str' object has no attribute 'get' when trying both awscli & boto3 in a python application. This is also impacting boto3 Stubber for unit tests locally.
File "/usr/local/Cellar/awscli/2.17.28/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/client.py", 
line 496, in _is_s3_dualstack_mode enabled = self.scoped_config.get('s3', {}).get(
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

aws-cli/2.17.28 Python/3.11.9 Darwin/23.6.0 source/x86_64

My config file has never changed
[default] 
region = us-east-1

I did find some stuff about adding s3 config, but that did not help
[default]
region = us-east-1
s3 =
    signature_version = s3v4


Those s3= and s3v4 configurations look a bit odd. If you remove them, does it work?


try reconfiguring cli using "aws configure"
try removing and reinstalling aws cli
second option helped me resolve the issue

